# Stop Main.cs from opening when an exception is thrown Xamarin

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin

Every time an exception is thrown (caught or not) my app crashes as expected but unexpectedly opens Main.cs.  Does anyone know why this happens and how to prevent it?

Using Xamarin for IOS in Visual Studio on a PC.  Happens on VS 2015 & VS 2017 Preview

Comment: I believe that somewhere in VS there is an option you can set for "break on unhandled exceptions" - disable that

Comment: Thank you @Jason!  That is exactly what I was looking for.  I just opened Tools and Setting and searched for "break" and found the right option to uncheck.